# How to secure Odoo default Administrator account?

Tags: odoo

The issue described below is experienced on Odoo 12 CE.

The default Administrator, who is created upon DB creation is of type Administrator/Settings. For simplicity we name it User1. User1 creates User2. User1 gives Administrator/Access Rights to User2. Now User2 is able to:

- Delete User 1 ?!?!
- Self promote to Administrator/Settings ?!?!

How can we prevent User2 from both actions above and thus secure User1?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. The `superuser`(or `Administrator` or `User1` as you call it) is **only** secured against **activating/deactivating** and **deleting**. However, you can remove `Administrator/Access Rights` from `superuser`'s rights.

We can see what's already done for securing the `superuser` in [`12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py) (`Users` class):

**Edit record method :**

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    if values.get('active') and SUPERUSER_ID in self._ids:
        raise UserError(_("You cannot activate the superuser."))
    if values.get('active') == False and self._uid in self._ids:
        raise UserError(_("You cannot deactivate the user you're currently logged in as."))
    ...
```

**Delete record method:**

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    if SUPERUSER_ID in self.ids:
        raise UserError(_('You can not remove the admin user as it is used internally for resources created by Odoo (updates, module installation, ...)'))
    db = self._cr.dbname
    for id in self.ids:
        self.__uid_cache[db].pop(id, None)
    self._invalidate_session_cache()
    return super(Users, self).unlink()
```

**What can we do to secure further ?:**

To prevent anyone (except the `superuser` it self) from touching the `superuser`, you can add following code at the beginning of the `write` method in the `Users` class (in path mentioned earlier) :

```
if SUPERUSER_ID in self.ids and self._uid != SUPERUSER_ID :
    raise UserError(_('You can not edit the admin!'))
```

Comment: don't forget to ident correctly the new code and restart the server for the changes to take effect.